# Adding square bracket to starting and ending of string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have String like this

```
var data1 = "Cust_Id","Name","Mobile","Email","Last_time_Interface"
"1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-01-21"
"1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-02-21"
"2","Sam","9980600255","Sam@gmail.com","2009-09-28";
```

But I need to convert it into like the below

```
var data = [["Cust_Id","Name","Mobile","Email","Last_time_Interface"],
["1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-01-21"],
["1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-02-21"],
["2","Sam","9980600255","Sam@gmail.com","2009-09-28"]];
```

Comment: That's invalid JavaScript. If you don't post the actual code/value there is not much we can do. Or do you mean that the whole text (`var data = ...;`) is in a string, i.e. `"var data = ...;"`?

Comment: Actually it is a csv file.but i want this to be in this format [["Cust_Id","Name","Mobile","Email","Last_time_Interface"], ["1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-01-21"], ["1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-02-21"], ["2","Sam","9980600255","Sam@gmail.com","2009-09-28"]]; the lines csv is not fixed.it will increase. –

Comment: I understand how you want the data to be. I don't know in which form you have the data originally, because, as I said, the first of your examples is invalid JS.

Comment: I have data in a csv format.I have to convert it into the above format and save it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the list of strings in an array, and you want to split it into chunks of 5 elements:

```
var data1 = ["Cust_Id","Name","Mobile","Email","Last_time_Interface",
    "1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-01-21",
    "1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-02-21",
    "2","Sam","9980600255","Sam@gmail.com","2009-09-28"],
    data;

_.mixin({
    chunk : function (array, unit) {
        if (!_.isArray(array)) return array;
        unit = Math.abs(unit);
        var results = [],
        length = Math.ceil(array.length / unit);

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            results.push(array.slice( i * unit, (i + 1) * unit));
        }
        return results;
    }
});
data = _.chunk(data1, 5);
console.clear();
console.log(data);
```

The [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/) extension [`chunk` is originally written by Larry Battle](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/696#issuecomment-13338480). Here is a [test page](http://jsfiddle.net/aK2h4/).

Comment: Actually it is a csv file.but i want this to be in this format [["Cust_Id","Name","Mobile","Email","Last_time_Interface"], ["1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-01-21"], ["1","Aruna","9980600155","Aruna@gmail.com","2013-02-21"], ["2","Sam","9980600255","Sam@gmail.com","2009-09-28"]]; the lines in csv is not fixed.it will increase.

Comment: How do you read the file? From the browser using HTML5 File API? Or form server code, for example using node.js File System API?

Comment: I have used ajax to read the file and The response is in the csv format.